# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the latest file name and its path so that I can select the latest file for processing. By latest I mean folder name and not per creation date.

Folders are created as:

```
03Mar22.zip
06Mar22.zip
10Mar22.zip
13Mar22.zip
```

The value stored in latestfilepath is  'C:/Users/ ABC /OneDrive - DEF /Run #1 PQR/13Mar22.zip'

When I am using the variable that to parse the path then I am getting  error as (AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seek') but when I am writing the Path directly then the code runs fine.
Can you please help me in identifying the issue?

The code that I am using is:

```
path = 'C:/Users/ABC/OneDrive - DEF/Run #1 PQR'
filesname = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.zip')]
filepath = list(glob.glob(path+'\*.zip'))
jobfilelist = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(filesname,filepath)), columns = ['Names', 'Path'])
jobfilelist['Foldername'] = jobfilelist['Names'].str.split('.').str[0]
jobfilelist['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(jobfilelist['Foldername'])
LatestDate = jobfilelist['Date'].max()
jobfilelist = jobfilelist.loc[jobfilelist ['Date'] == LatestDate]
latestfilname = jobfilelist['Names']
latestfilepath = "'"+path +"/"+ latestfilname+"'"
extractZip = ZipFile(latestfilepath)
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-568a6494aeee> in <module>
      3 #extractZip1 = 'C:/Users/ABC/OneDrive - DEF/Run #1 PQR/13Mar22.zip'
      4 
----> 5 extractZip = ZipFile(latestfilepath)
      6 
      7 #extractZip = ZipFile('C:/Users/ABC/OneDrive - DEF/Run #1 PQR/13Mar22.zip')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel)
   1223         try:
   1224             if mode == 'r':
-> 1225                 self._RealGetContents()
   1226             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1227                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1286         fp = self.fp
   1287         try:
-> 1288             endrec = _EndRecData(fp)
   1289         except OSError:
   1290             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _EndRecData(fpin)
    257 
    258     # Determine file size
--> 259     fpin.seek(0, 2)
    260     filesize = fpin.tell()
    261 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5178                 return self[name]
-> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5180 
   5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Comment: do `print(latestfilname)` you'll see that it is not what you exepct

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please suggest how to fix it.

If I print(latestfilname), I get the latest file name.. Which is "22Mar2022.zip"

Comment: It would help to post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). And please try to make a [mre], meaning reduce your code to just the relevant parts.

Comment: Now that you see what latestfilname is, and is not. don't you have an idea to go one string ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate.. I am very new to Python... Just beginner..

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution. As you said I edited code for latestfilname as

```
latestfilname = jobfilelist['Names'].values[0]
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help